# Ejecutar llamada axios luego de 5 segundos

Tags: javascript, axios

Tengo una petición axios que realizo al buscar en un select:

```
const loadOptions=  async(inputValue, callback) =>{
const queryOptions = { filter: `contains(Name, '${inputValue}' )`};
const response = await axios
.post("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/all/RUBROS", queryOptions)
const json = await response.data.detailscallback(json.map(i=>({label:i.Name, value: i.Code})))}
```

Lo que hace el `select` es que busca al *abrirlo*, lo que quiero hacer es realizar la petición luego de unos segundos, por que si no se me disparan varías peticiones con cada caracter que introduzca el usuario. Hasta ahora no he encontrado nada con axios para poder realizarlo.

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar `setTimeout`?

Comment: No se como implementarlo en la llamada axios

Comment: No se exactamente como tienes el resto de tu código, pero en donde sea que llames a la función `loadOptions` puedes retrasar su ejecución 5 segundos usando `setTimeout(() => loadOptions(inputValue, callback),  5000);`

Comment: No entiendo lo de tipear. El select normal de html cambia cuando se elige alguna de sus options. Ahi es cuado al evento change deberias hacer la peticion.

Answer (score 0):

si quieres que se demore unos segundos al responder la petición podrías usar

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Hola Mundo");
}, 2000);
```

el valor **2000** hace referencia al tiempo que demora en responder en formato de de miliesegundo.
el **console.log("Hola Mundo");** remplazarlo con tu código.

Comment: No me funciona, ya que el select recibe un  loadOptions={loadOptions} y no es posible pasarle una funcion